# BLIF outputed by yosys involves DFF, and the BLIF file cannot be read by ABC

Tags: yosys, berkeley-abc

I'm new to yosys and ABC for logic synthesis. I downloaded one design [aes_core](https://opencores.org/projects/apbtoaes128) from opencores, and run the following script with yosys to map the design into blif:

```
read_verilog ./designs/apbtoaes128/trunk/rtl/*.v
hierarchy -check -top aes_core
proc
techmap -map ./oss-cad-suite/share/yosys/adff2dff.v
synth
dfflibmap -prepare ./yosys-yosys-0.23/manual/PRESENTATION_Intro/mycells.lib 
abc -liberty ./yosys-yosys-0.23/manual/PRESENTATION_Intro/mycells.lib
dfflibmap -liberty ./yosys-yosys-0.23/manual/PRESENTATION_Intro/mycells.lib 
write_blif  -gates ./designs/aes_core.blif
```

After this, the blif only contains five types of gates (BUF, NOT, NAND, NOR, DFF); one snippet of the blif file is as follows:

```
...
.gate DFF C=clk D=$auto$rtlil.cc:2560:MuxGate$25762 Q=rd_count[0]
.gate DFF C=clk D=$auto$rtlil.cc:2560:MuxGate$25766 Q=rd_count[1]
.gate DFF C=clk D=$auto$rtlil.cc:2560:MuxGate$25770 Q=rd_count[2]
.gate DFF C=clk D=$auto$rtlil.cc:2560:MuxGate$25774 Q=rd_count[3]
.gate DFF C=clk D=$abc$11428$auto$fsm_map.cc:170:map_fsm$2040[0] Q=state[0]
.gate DFF C=clk D=$abc$11428$auto$fsm_map.cc:170:map_fsm$2040[1] Q=state[1]
.gate DFF C=clk D=$abc$11428$auto$fsm_map.cc:170:map_fsm$2040[2] Q=state[2]
.gate DFF C=clk D=$abc$11428$auto$fsm_map.cc:118:implement_pattern_cache$2077 Q=state[3]
.gate DFF C=clk D=$abc$11428$auto$fsm_map.cc:170:map_fsm$2040[4] Q=state[4]
...
```

At last, I wish to use ABC to read the blif file, the script I used with ABC is:

```
read ./yosys-yosys-0.23/manual/PRESENTATION_Intro/mycells.lib 
read_blif ./designs/aes_core.blif
```

And the output is:

```
Generic file reader requires a known file extension to open "./yosys-yosys-0.23/manual/PRESENTATION_Intro/mycells.h".
Line 393: Cannot find gate "DFF" in the library.
Reading network from file has failed.
```

It seems that when I read the cell library in ABC, the sequential gate is skipped, and I wonder the reason of this and how can we fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, ABC does not support DFF and only supports FF. You can try using the Yosys command 'clk2fflogic' to address this issue. This command combines the clock with logic to generate a logic netlist consisting only of FFs. To use it, you need to convert your Verilog HDL code into Yosys internal representation, then use the 'clk2fflogic' command. Finally, you can import the output netlist into ABC for further processing.